# Module not found: ESM packages (supports-color) need to be imported. Use 'import' to reference the package instead

Tags: next.js

can someone help me with it : Module not found: ESM packages (supports-color) need to be imported. Use 'import' to reference the package instead. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/import-esm-externals

i had it when i write command npm run dev to run my project i did not expect this error at all

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

A quick workaround is to install `supports-color@8.1.1` (the version is important)

https://github.com/debug-js/debug/issues/912
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49718
https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/issues/1424